# Using the resulting object from require call in ClojureScript?

Tags: npm, clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop, shadow-cljs

In JavaScript there is the idiom:

```js
const ScrollTrigger = require('ScrollTrigger-classes');

var trigger = new ScrollTrigger({
  once: true
 });
```

How do I do the same thing in ClojureScript using Shadow-CLJS for npm modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferably you do this via the `ns`.

```
(ns your.thing
  (:require ["ScrollTrigger-classes" :as ScrollTrigger]))

(let [trigger (ScrollTrigger. #js {:once true})]
  ...)
```

If you must you can just use `(let [ScrollTrigger (js/require "...") ...] ...)`.

Comment: That works, thanks. I was missing the trailing dot. Still can't trigger a scroll position with it, but that is a different question...